# How to put the textbox and a button inline in cakephp

Tags: css, forms, cakephp

I am trying to get the textbox and submit button inline on the top of my default layout page for search purposes, but instead the submit button falls under the textbox, messing up my layout. I tried this

```
    echo $this->Form->create('Service', array(
        'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'search'), $this->params['pass'])
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input('service_title', array('label' => false)).$this->Form->end(__('Find'));
```

I don't know whether it's a css issue but normal html tags display just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, and how does the "abnormal" HTML tags that Cake generates look like...? I'm pretty sure Cake generates normal HTML.

**This is a pure CSS problem.**

If you need to give your inputs a specific class you can do that:

```
$this->Form->input('some_field', array(
    'class' => 'some-class',
    'id' => 'some-specific-id'
));
```

Then write your CSS according to whatever you want it to look like.

Comment: Thanks, I had the code in a div tag already and assumed it would work... Gues I'm having a long day

Comment: Well what is the exact issue then!? You want to modify the div?

Comment: The div tag wasn't properly formatted on the css page... So it was a css issue

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp add extra tags... for inline inputs and buttons add option `div => false`, like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('service_title', array('div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'myClassName'));
```

You set form option `inputDefaults` in Your form for your all inputs too, like:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Service', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false
    )
));
```

Then You don't have to set `div => false` for every input, read more about forms: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html